# Minimizing a Maximum Row/Column/Diagonal Sum of Arrangement of $\{1, \cdots, n^2\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, combinatorial-designs

Consider an arrangement of $\{1, \cdots, n^2\}$ into an $n \times n$ square. 
Let $r$ be the maximum row sum, $c$ be the maximum column sum, and $d$ be the maximum of the main diagonal and antidiagonal sums.

We want to minimize the maximum $m$ of $r$, $c$, and $d$ over all such arrangements.

For example, if we arranged $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ into a $2 \times 2$ square as:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
\end{matrix}
$$

then $r = 7, c = 6, d = 5$, so $m = 7$, which is optimal in this case (since the 4 entry must be paired with the 3 entry).

If we instead considered $3 \times 3$, an arrangement could be:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 9 & 2\\
8 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7
\end{matrix}
$$

In this one, we have $r = 18, c = 18, d = 11$, so $m \le 18$.

Is there a name for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any size of at least $3 \times 3$ you can make a [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).  All the sums will be the same, $\frac 12n(n^2+1)$.  This is clearly optimal because the sum of the row sums is the sum of all the numbers in the grid.  If one gets smaller, another must get larger.  For $3 \times 3$ it is
$$\begin{matrix}
8 & 1 & 6\\
3 & 5 & 7\\
4 & 9 & 2
\end{matrix}$$
with all the sums being $15$.  For $3 \times 3$ this is unique up to rotation and reflection.  For larger sizes there are many.

Comment: Of course, I saw magic squares and somehow didn't make the connection of "all equal sums" means that it is optimal. Thanks!